# Location of Outlook dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

I have my C#, Asp.net website which Opens my outlook mail item on clicking a button. I have added Microsoft.office.interop.outlook.dll version 12.0 to my bin from .NET.

While running the application, from which location it will take my dll. Either from bin or from GAC?

Because I have installed Outlook in my local machine. so I can able to run my code. But once I publish the code to Server, I could not able to run my application. I dont have outlook dll in my server.

Please suggest

Comment: You cannot open an email client on a client machine from a web server. You can add a `mailto:` link to your web page and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook, or any other Office app, cannot be used from a service (such as IIS). Even if you could, you would still need to have Outlook installed on the machine where your code runs.